# Why does my profile consist of numbers instead of my username?

Tags: steam

On Steam, my profile is the following:

> http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197964085566/

Notice the numbers at the tail end of the URL. While other users also have numbers for a profile like mine, I've seen many others users with their usernames in their profile instead. It makes it a lot easier to link and remember your profile page based on a short username instead of a couple dozen integers.

**Why do some users have a username in their profile instead of numbers and vice versa? Is there a way to change this?**

I originally thought it was based on the age of the account since I was a pretty early adopter back on January 24, 2004, but I've seen new and old accounts with numbers and usernames.

---

*Update:* I've since updated my profile URL so clicking the above link will renavigate to the following:

> http://steamcommunity.com/id/johnjon

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this isn't a random collection of numbers - it's actually your [SteamID in a different form.](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamID#Steam_ID_as_a_Steam_Community_ID)  Online tools [also exist](http://steamidconverter.com/) to convert between this number, your shortened profile URL, and your SteamID.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can change this in your community profile - change the "Custom URL" field to whatever you wish the URL to end with.

Here's the step by step breakdown:

- Load the [Steam Community website](http://steamcommunity.com)
- Login, if you aren't already, and make sure you're on the "Home" tab
- On the right side, under "Actions" choose "Edit my Profile"
- Click the "Profile" tab if it is not already highlighted
- Change the value for "Custom URL" - the "http://steamcommunity.com/id/" part cannot be changed.
- Click the bright green "Save" button at the bottom

[image]

Comment: I don't see the option to do that anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

In your steam community profile, click the `Edit my Profile` link.

[image]

One of the headings on the page will be `Custom URL`:

[image]

Once you enter text in this box and save settings, your profile will then be accessible by this URL as well as your current `http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/[id]/` URL.